# JSP como incluir um select dentro de um checkbox

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web, com *java spring mvc*, e preciso listar itens em um checkboxList dinamico e incluir um select option em cada item.

Algo que no html seria semelhante ao código abaixo:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox"> Item 1 - 
            <select>
                <option value="1">Ativo</option>
                <option value="2">Inativo</option>
                <option value="3">Bloqueado</option>
            </select>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox"> Item 2 - 
            <select>
                <option value="1">Ativo</option>
                <option value="2">Inativo</option>
                <option value="3">Bloqueado</option>
            </select>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox"> Item 3 - 
            <select>
                <option value="1">Ativo</option>
                <option value="2">Inativo</option>
                <option value="3">Bloqueado</option>
            </select>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Como eu consigo fazer isso de maneira dinamica no jsp?
Lembrando que os itens do checkbox vem do banco de dados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você estiver usando JSP com JSTL, inclua no começo do arquivo:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
```

E em cada lugar que você precisar do select, coloque

```
<select>
<c:forEach var="item" items="${algumBean.listaDeAlgumaCoisa}">
  <option value="${fn:escapeXml(item.valor)}">${fn:escapeXml(item.descricao)}</option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
```

`listaDeAlgumaCoisa`deverá ser uma lista de objetos onde cada um contém um campo chamado `valor` e um campo chamado `descricao`. Como tornar o objeto `algumBean` disponível para a página depende um pouco do framework, e eu nunca fiz nenhum projeto com o Spring, mas não deve ser difícil.

Lembrando que com Java e Spring é possível usar diversas *linguagens de template*, como JSP (com JSTL e também outras *bibliotecas de tags*), Thymeleaf, FreeMarker, etc. Como o seu exemplo é em HTML puro, não pude conferir o que você está usando, fiz o exemplo usando apenas JSP com JSTL.

Answer (score 1):

Fala Erico. Tudo blza ?

Bom, em uma pagina JSP você pode utilizar as tags de abertura e fechamento de código java dentro de uma pagina JSP. EX:

```
            <select>
                <%
                   List<String> resultado = ClasseDAO.pegarResultado();
                   for(String valor : resultado ){
                     out.println("<option value=\"" + valor + "\" >" + valor  + "</option>");
                   }
                 %>
            </select>
```

Comment: Cara, obrigado, sua resposta ajuda e resolve de maneira rápida, mas se a gente seguir as boas práticas, não é muito legal a gente colocar códigos java na jsp, muito menos invocar uma classe DAO. Mas como eu estou meio que iniciando nos jsp, saber desse recurso já é uma grande ajuda.